# Error 3167 - "Record is deleted" when running an append query. ACCESS 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm attempting to run an append query to a linked table (access backend) and I'm getting Error 3167, Record is deleted. I can't seem to find the offending record. But if I change the table to a local table and run the append query, it runs with no problems at all. I've attempted a compact and repair but it's not helped at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a multiuser database? Have you run the compact on the front-end or back-end database?

Comment: It is a mulituser. I've run on both back end and front end.

Comment: You could get this message while a user has deleted a record in your queryset in the background. Are you doing this with VBA and transactions or just running the append query manually?

Comment: I have a series of queries that automatically run every night. It also happens if I do it manually. But if works fine if it's a local table and not linked to the backend.

Comment: More details the better to solve. Do you create the local table by importing the linked table or is it a separate one used for testing? Does the query fail when you manually run the macro with the series of queries - or just the one query?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the SQL for your append query?

Comment: I created the local table just by copying the linked table and pasting. It asked if you want to create a local table with structure and data. I have a series of about 30 queries that run on that macro, with the ninth query in the series being the one that fails. If a run each query manually it will still fail on the 9th query.

Comment: Show the SQL for the 8th and 9th queries.

Comment: It's not the SQL. The sql has been the same and has not changed at all. It has something to do with it being a linked table because if the table is local, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Then copy the backend file _as is_ to a local folder and relink. Will that run smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it was popping up with "Record is deleted" when it was trying to append a primary key that was already there. It never had that issue before. So I just added to the where criteria:

"table.id NOT IN (SELECT ID from table)"

Runs perfectly now. Have no idea why it started though.

Thank you for everyone's input.